# Selenium Python: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the 'innerhtml' nested within the element:

```
<select name="cmbCameras" id="cmbCameras" onchange="GetCameraByID($(this).val());" class="Textbox" style="width:254px;">
```

My code as of now is:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.gatewayguide.com/")
time.sleep(10)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
html = driver.find_element_by_id("cmbCameras")
elem = html.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

However selenium can never locate the element I want. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there are multiple `iframe` tags on the page. You need the second one:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[1])
```